# Relative and absolute font sizes in R: Mixing native and ggplot2 methods

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, font-size

The `ggplot()` function and anything built on top of it ignores the global point size. Functions like `plot()` and `text()`, however, do not. The former functions expect font sizes to be specified in absolute terms, through a `size` parameter, while the latter work with `cex`, which does relative scaling.

It's not always possible to avoid mixing those mechanisms. Here's an example: You want to plot a series of polygons and place labels inside them, typically for a map. Especially for highly nonconvex polygons, you might want to use `rgeos::polygonsLabel()` (rather than, say, `coordinates()`) to determine appropriate label positions. This function is built on top of `text()` and thus, again, only allows you to pass relative font sizes. But maybe you later want to place the labels with `geom_text()` from the ggplot2 package; for optimal utility of the `rgeos::polygonsLabel()` output, font sizes need to match here.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the following example to work as expected and would like to share it since it took me a while to get there. Please correct me if I'm doing something that I shouldn't be, e.g. with the point-to-mm conversion. I'll create a PNG image file for this compatibility with this site but, e.g., SVG and PDF work just as well.

```
pointSize <- 20 # or whatever you want

# Setting point size here affects the native plotting methods
# like text()
png('myfigure.png', pointsize=pointSize) # apparent default: 12

library(ggplot2)
plot.new()

pointToMM = function(x) 0.352778*x

# plot a few 'o's
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = 'o')) +
  geom_text(size = pointToMM(pointSize)) # apparent default: pointToMM(11)

# label the axes in the same
p <- p + labs(x = 'xo xo xo xo xo xo', y = 'xo xo xo xo xo xo') +
  theme_bw(pointSize) # apparent default: 12

print(p)

# Add 'xo' in two places. Notice how the sizes match up.
# The x and y coordinates were chosen ad-hoc for this example
text(0.35,0.13, 'xo')
text(0.5, 0.0, 'xo')

dev.off()
```

[image: sample plot]