# geom_label doesn't scale correspondingly to plot in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

While building up my Shiny App I came across situation where `ggplot2` graphic looks very different with different window sizes. The first graphic shows the plot in full desktop size - everything works great:
[image]

However, when I change the size of output window every element seems to scale down properly, but not `geom_label` (see the graphic below).

[image]

Why is that a case and how can I make the `geom_label` to scale down correspondigly?

The Shiny set-up is:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

      mainPanel(
         selectInput('cluster', '', 1:7),
         plotOutput('ap_plot', height = 200)
       )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ap_plot <- renderPlot({
    data %>% 
      filter(cluster == input$cluster) %>% 
      plot_sequences(.by = ts_cluster, .colour = id)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Interesting question, essentially you want to add something like `aes(size=window_res)` which would scale things based on the resolution (extrinsic of course, not within the data). BTW, I think the lines and arrows are a little thicker (relatively) in the second example, so perhaps things don't always scale down, perhaps just "don't scale less-badly"?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36547591/3358272

Comment: Yes, kind of. I do not bother much about lines, but it can be easily observed that `geom_rect` scales down, and `geom_label` doesn't. Unfortunetely, I can't see how the link you provided may be related - could you possibly elaborate in an answer?

Comment: Just the use of `pointToMM(pointSize)` to dynamically set your font `size=` so that you can work around the problem. I don't think it's an ideal solution (you are unlikely to want to call `plot.new()` within shiny), which is why I did not mark this as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I'm afraid pointSize is not changing as well, so defining geom_label size based on pointSize doesn't work. Shouldn't I rather dynamically set size based on windows width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As detailed [in the shiny documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html) the plot width for the current plot is defined within `session$client_data$output_<plotname>_width`, so for your example `session$client_data$output_ap_plot_width`. This can be used to scale the text argument of `geom_label`. You don't provide a minimal reproducible example, but here's one:

```
data <- tibble(
  cluster = sample(7, 100, replace = TRUE),
  x = rnorm(100),
  y = rnorm(100)
)

plot_sequences <- function(data_set, width) {
  label_data <- data_set %>% 
    summarise(
      n = n(),
      mean_x = mean(x),
      mean_y = mean(y),
      label = sprintf("N: %d\nMean x: %0.3f\nMean y: %0.3f", n, n, mean_x, mean_y)
    )

  ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_label(aes(x = 1.5, y = 1.5, label = label), label_data, size = 4 / 900 * width)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    width = 12,
    selectInput('cluster', '', 1:7),
    plotOutput('ap_plot', height = 200)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  width <- 400
  output$ap_plot <- renderPlot(execOnResize = TRUE, {
    data %>% 
      filter(cluster == input$cluster) %>% 
      plot_sequences(session$clientData[["output_ap_plot_width"]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can see that my plot function takes the plot width as an input and then scales the text size accordingly, using a width of 900 pixels as a baseline. Note also that I've set `execOnResize` to be `TRUE`, since otherwise the plot is replayed rather than recalculated when the window/plot are resized.